# sql server query for update rows which are multiple of 2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've a table with many rows. I've to meet the requirement that those rows which are multiple of 2 should only be updated. e.g.

```
update [DBO].[ZZZ_FKP_FEMALE_FULLNAME_TBL]
set remarks = 'multiple of TWO'
--- update only those rows which are multiple of 2.
--- where ID = MULTIPLE OF 2
here ID column is primary key with auto increment
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: where modulo 2 = 0

Comment: @jarlh Thank You! please can you provide the complete answer.

Comment: I hope this is just practicing. No need to store such computed value in a table. (Check out computed column instead.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use modulo as @jarlh said, here is the code:

```
UPDATE T SET T.remarks = 'multiple of TWO'
FROM [DBO].[ZZZ_FKP_FEMALE_FULLNAME_TBL] AS T
WHERE ID % 2 = 0
```

Comment: What is the benefit of using ALIAS in update statement? Can you please explain?

Comment: in this example, only better to understand it visually. 
in other cases, you may want to join tables and update one of them using second tables values, for example: `UPDATE a SET a.ID = b.ID FROM dbo.Table1 AS a INNER JOIN dbo.Table2 AS b ON a.[SomeField] = b.[SomeField]`

Answer (score 0):

```
update [DBO].[ZZZ_FKP_FEMALE_FULLNAME_TBL] set remarks = 'multiple of TWO'where ID % 2 = 0
```